# Where does Visual Studio save a reference to sign certificate?

Tags: visual-studio, manifest, signing

cannot find out where VS saves a click once sign certificate reference. The only change that happens in csproj file when one toggles between click once is this:

```
<SignManifests>true</SignManifests>
```

or

```
<SignManifests>true</SignManifests>
```

My question is, how does VS know which certificate to use when SignManifests is true?

.pom.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found the answer myself. It's the `<ManifestCertificateThumbprint>` entry that references the selected certificate. If you want to view what your resolved certificate is, then you can use a build target from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/422ca4e3-fa65-4c25-a1a1-03efff5c2eb6/why-does-publisheridentity-not-match-certificate).